# This can't be a proof that the set theory is inconsistent?

Tags: logic, set-theory

I have an illusion that this idea that I found proves that ZF is inconsistent. But, of course, I don't want to accept it so I would appreciate to know what is it that I did wrong here. Does there exist any known result which resembles this?

The idea is to, firstly, construct a set of all constructible sets and then, secondly, say that it cannot be a set because I can construct the power set of that set which would mean that I constructed a set bigger than any constructible set. To construct a set of all constructible sets, I firstly formalized all math texts by saying that all mathematical texts can be written using only a fixed set of characters (finite, but it may be countably infinite too). Then, I formalized the syntax of these texts, for example, stating that I can't write $\land$ after $\land$, or introducing formulas which check the logic, for example, if I have one statement saying "$p$ is true" and other saying "$p$ is false" then the text is not syntactically correct. The set of all mathematical texts is countable and I can define (using restricted comprehension) the countable set of all correct mathematical texts. Then, I can (well, I hope I can't, but it seems to me that I can) define a formula which "evaluates" these texts. Here is what I mean: Say all texts consist of lines of text. In each line I either (1) defined a new object (a new set) or (2) wrote a logical statement using some logical rule on some of the previous statements or some of the axioms. My evaluating formula will "scan" the text and examine each line in which I defined a new set (meaning type 1). It will then evaluate that set and add it in a global thing called "set of all constructed sets". At the end of this "process", my evaluating formula has created the set of all contructible sets (using the axiom schema of replacement because at each $n$ I constructed one set, so I had a functor from $\mathbb{N}$ to the class of sets, not a *function*, but this axiom saves the mess because $\mathbb{N}$ is a set).

This is how I "show" that it is possible to construct a set of all constructible sets which leads to a contradiction as I explained in the beginning of the second paragraph. My guesses at what went wrong here are: 1. maybe I assumed somehow implicitly that ZF is complete (meaning that it proves every true statement) or that it proves its own consistency, 2. I used some logic of too high order or 3. that my evaluating formula would "get stuck" in an infinite recursion at evaluating the text which does exactly what I described in the second paragraph.

Comment: Defining a formula that "evaluates" a string from inside the model you're in is exactly the problem, as I understand it. See [this](https://mathoverflow.net/a/44129) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tarski%27s_undefinability_theorem). If you try and write down a function in ZF which "parses" a string of symbols and outputs the set it defines, you'll (hopefully) find you can't do it. You'll have to give more detail if you want us to point out the mistake! There's several obstacles - one is the model might contain nonstandard naturals, and therefore strings of nonstandard length...

Comment: @IzaakvanDongen That second link seems very helpful. Thank you! I will explore.

Comment: Your idea (which, as others explained, won't work for showing the inconsistency of set theory) is closely related to [Richard's paradox](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Richard%27s_paradox).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very interesting idea! However the problem, in part, is with the evaluating function and what you expect it to do. What is the expression corresponding to the set of all constructible sets? You  will see that you will have to define the whole construction you're trying to make, but when defining it again, you will have to define an expression corresponding to the set of all constructible sets, and so on. So it's a circular argument.

Comment: Yes! I agree. However, I unfortunately can't see how it makes my construction non-existent. So, your argument is, approximately, my third guess at why my idea is wrong. But again, I can't help but to see it as yet another contradiction in this. To me it seems like I did everything properly, and then later I somehow reasoned out that what I did doesn't exist. That's how a contradiction in ZF would look like: we do something properly and at the end we derive a contradiction. But if we didn't suppose anything, then there is no contradiction.

Comment: I hope you understood what I mean

Comment: In short, I see your argument as an alternative to my finishing argument "the set of all constructible sets is bigger than itself therefore ZF is inconsistent". Yours would be: "formula for the set of all constructible sets both exists and doesn't exist so ZF is inconsistent".

Comment: Not quite, it is not that the function gets stuck. The point is that there is no expression corresponding to the set of all constructible sets. I suspect the function can be defined correctly, but its domain is smaller than what is needed for the full argument to go on. To emphasize, the formula for the set of all constructible sets doesn't exist (and that's it).

Comment: My expression for "evaluating" formula would be: break the line which introduced a new set into primary steps of that construction. Then each step is simple and uses some of the axioms: union, power set, restricted comprehension or axiom schema of replacement. Then, each of this primitive lines takes one set which is already constructed (say, I did it at the timepoint $n$) and then one of these 4 things is applied to it to define a new set at the current timepoint. I just don't see how this is wrong :(

Comment: Okay, I see your point now. I should try to define that expression in more detail and see it myself.